# Компиляция apk на Android в unity портит 3д модельку

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, apk

Может кто знает что это может быть? Вот смотрите это моделька Иви в редакторе там все хорошо, но когда игра скомпилирована то на моем Xiaomi получаем вот это (1 картинка)[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8NKc.jpg)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинки не одинаковые, присмотритесь на плечах Иви некрасиво вылазят текстурки на экране смартфона выглядит отвратительно.
Немного прояснил задачу. Артефакты вылазят из-за анимации модели, пока Иви стоит в стандартной позе раскинув руки все нормально как только она их сжимает, то в скомпилированом приложении идут артефакты, что интерестно в эдиторе юнити никаких артефактов нету. Что делать не знаю.

Comment: В чем проблема то? Предлагаете найти 10 отличий самим? :) укажите пожалуйста что именно вас беспокоит.

Comment: Не специалист в этом, но кажется логичным поиграться с Texture Compression (File > Build Settings). Попробовать режимы ETC и ETC2 32-bit.

Comment: `вот это`  да!... всё горит.

Comment: ssa112112 спс счас попробую

Comment: Я указал отличия